# Trying to convert a C++ project to a static library compatible with CLR

Tags: c++, clr

So I've managed to compile a project I was developing into a .lib, successfully, using the /clr flag. What I'm now struggling to do is create a CLR Class Library wrapper for it, to allow me to use it with .NET.

I'm getting the following errors when I try compile my CLR Class Library:

```
Renderer.obj : error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A000017) "public: __thiscall cMain::cMain(void)" (??0cMain@@$$FQAE@XZ) referenced in function "private: void __clrcall Renderer::GraphicsBox::NewGraphicsBox(int,int,int,int)" (?NewGraphicsBox@GraphicsBox@Renderer@@$$FA$AAMXHHHH@Z)

Renderer.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall cMain::cMain(void)" (??0cMain@@$$FQAE@XZ) referenced in function "private: void __clrcall Renderer::GraphicsBox::NewGraphicsBox(int,int,int,int)" (?NewGraphicsBox@GraphicsBox@Renderer@@$$FA$AAMXHHHH@Z)
```

I've added the relevant entries to the include directories, as well as the relevant entries to the lib directories.

Code looks like this:

stdafx.h

```
#pragma once

#include "cMain.h"
```

Renderer.h

```
#pragma once

#include "Stdafx.h"



using namespace System;

namespace Renderer {

    public ref class GraphicsBox
    {
        GraphicsBox();
        ~GraphicsBox();

        void NewGraphicsBox(System::Int32 scrw, System::Int32 scrh, System::Int32 posx, System::Int32 posy);
        // TODO: Add your methods for this class here.
    };
}
```

Renderer.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include "Renderer.h"

pragma comment(lib "DX11test.lib")

using namespace Renderer;

GraphicsBox::GraphicsBox()
{

}

GraphicsBox::~GraphicsBox()
{

}

void GraphicsBox::NewGraphicsBox(System::Int32 scrw, System::Int32 scrh, System::Int32 posx, System::Int32 posy)
{
    cMain *base;

    bool result;

    base = new cMain;
    if (!base)
    {
        throw runtime_error("Failed at base = cMain");
    }
}
```

And the class I'm trying to reference:

cMain.h

```
#ifndef _CMAIN_H_
#define _CMAIN_H_

#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#include <Windows.h>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <string>

#include "InputHandler.h"
#include "cGraphics.h"
#include "cVehicleObject.h"
#include "cVehicleModel.h"
#include "cTerrainModel.h"
#include "cLight.h"

using namespace std;

public class cMain
{
public:
    cMain();
    cMain(const cMain& other);
    ~cMain();

    bool Initialize(int scrWidth, int scrHeight);
    void Shutdown();
    void Run();

    LRESULT CALLBACK MessageHandler(HWND hwnd, UINT umessage, WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam);
private:
    bool Frame();
    void InitializeWindows(int& scrw, int& scrh);
    void CreateNewWindow(int& scrw, int& scrh, int posx, int posy);
    void ShutdownWindows();

    void ErrorDump(vector<string> errors, string filename);
    void ErrorDump(string error, string filename);

    bool SetUpLights();
    bool SetUpObjects();

    LPCWSTR m_applicationName;
    HINSTANCE m_hinstance;
    HWND m_hwnd;

    InputHandler* m_input;
    cGraphics* m_graphics;

    cObject::GameObjects m_gameObjects;

    vector<cLight> m_lights;
};

static LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT umessage, WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam);
static cMain* ApplicationHandle = 0;

#endif
```

My instincts tell me it's something to do with the usage of the Windows API within the project I'm trying to set up as a lib, but I'm inexperienced in linking things together so I honestly have no idea.

I want to convert the whole thing to be entirely CLR friendly, I don't want to leave any stone unturned. Thanks for the help

Comment: The build system doesn't warn enough about this, but static link libraries containing managed code is not supported.  The .NET equivalent is an assembly.

Answer (score 0):

Linker errors has nothing to do with include path of your program, it is related to implementation of the function. In your posted example I don't see `cMain.cpp`, so may be you forget to implement it or you just forget to implement `cMain::cMain()`

Comment: I can assure you I have most certainly implemented cMain::cMain(). I decided to leave the code out for cMain.cpp, as it's a rather large file.